# Mac: Rails not working!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

When I run the command `rails -v` the output is: `-bash: /usr/bin/rails: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` I've tried everything. I really need help on this. I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and I don't have any gems installed.

Comment: can you show us your gem list? `gem list --local` and please your ruby version `ruby -v` which rails are you using? I think rails 3? show us this too `which rails`

Comment: How did you install rails? What do you get when you run `which rails`?

Comment: I get /usr/bin/rails. I had it installed perfectly but I guess something I did broke it. It came with Developers Tools.

Answer (score 2):

Standard answer:

> First thing you should do if you want
>   to work with Ruby/Rails -- install RVM

http://rvm.io/

Comment: We can help you to install it :) This is great tool to work with rubies and gems

Comment: I voted this up. even though it is not the answer it is still needed :)

Comment: THis is not a straight answer, but it is a __fundamental answer__ :)

Comment: Although it is a useful tool, it's far easier to stick with the system version of ruby (1.8.7 I believe) to begin with. They can always grab 1.9.2 via RVM later on. Also, this does not answer the question.

Comment: Ok what do I type into terminal

Comment: @robinjam, actually your answer isn't answer too :) Our answers looks more like comments. My apologies to topic author :)

Comment: 1. Install [git](http://git-scm.com/download), 2. run this in Terminal `bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )`

Comment: @robinjam, with rails 3 you can better use 1.9.2 as i had a lot of problems with 1.8.7 + without rvm

Comment: If RVM is installed open in your text editor (or create) file `~/.bash_profile` and add this at the bottom `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`

Comment: now you can install Ruby 1.8.7 (I prefer Ruby Enterprise Edition {REE}): `rvm install ree`

Comment: Or even 1.9.2. 1.8.7 is the version included with OS X - the version you told him not to use...

Comment: @robinjam I told that? @jmeyer10 with what? What  have you done already?

Comment: I installed everything so now what do I do? Do I try installing rails again?

Comment: He has got problems with entire stack: Ruby, RubyGems. So let's just simplify that job

Comment: Set `rvm --default ree` and then `gem install rails`

Comment: OK I'll try that. It is still installing.

Comment: I think its hanging on: ree-1.8.7-2011.03 - #installing

Comment: thats all. After that you can instal any version you want: `rvm install 1.9.2` for example. then you can switch to each version: `rvm use ree`, `rvm use 1.9.2`. But remember. Each version needs its own gem package. So you will need to install Rails and other gems for each version of Ruby

Comment: you can. what will return: `gem -v`

Comment: Ill be right back in like 7 hours. it's about 3 a.m. in Moscow :)

Comment: It's probably not hanging - it takes a long time to compile ruby, you know.

Comment: installing rails almost worked this time error: ERROR:  While generating documentation for builder-2.1.2
... MESSAGE:   Unhandled special: Special: type=17, text="<!-- HI -->"
... RDOC args: --ri --op /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/builder-2.1.2/ri --title Builder -- Easy XML Building --main README --line-numbers lib CHANGES Rakefile README doc/releases/builder-1.2.4.rdoc doc/releases/builder-2.0.0.rdoc doc/releases/builder-2.1.1.rdoc --title builder-2.1.2 Documentation --quiet

Comment: lets take this into the chat. There is now 30 coments

Comment: `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc`

Answer (score 0):

"...and I don't have any gems installed."

Rails is a gem. Have you tried `sudo gem install rails`?

Comment: Rubygems can be quite slow. Leave it to do its work, don't Ctrl-C out.

Comment: Try `sudo gem update --system` first to grab the latest version of rubygems. Then do `sudo gem install rails` afterwards to grab the latest version of rails, which is currently 3.0.6. Then try `which rails` and post the output. Also, stop deleting your comments! It's hard to keep up!

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but I get this error:WARNING:  Invalid .gemspec format in '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/rubygems-update-1.6.1.gemspec'

Comment: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    HTTP Response 302 fetching http://gems.rubyforge.org/yaml

Comment: Rubygems didn't update then. This is really strange - ruby sort of 'just works' on my computer.